# cgi perl - file timestamp does not be read correctly

Tags: perl, file, cgi, timestamp

I have a problem with file timestamps in a CGI environment.

My cgi-script gets called once every minute by cron.

This cgi script fetches some text data (a message) via http from an external source and writes it to a file.
Before that it checks the last modification timestamp of this file and reads the old content of the file. 
I'm reading the file timestamp with

```
$fileage = (-M $filename) * 24 * 60;
```

If the file timestamp is older than 5 minutes and the new message is not identical to the old one, it does send it out to some other source.

See code fragments below.

My problem now: The script is running perfectly once every minute for 30 to 50 minutes and then suddenly the file age starts not to get read correctly as if the file was cached.
Instead of returning the correct file age which should be always around 5 to 7 minutes, the read file age increases to 10 minutes, 15 minutes, 20 minutes etc, though the file is written constantly every few minutes.

System is a Linux 2.6.16.60-0.42.10-bigsmp, Perl version : 5.008008, Webserver: Apache 2

```
use CGI;
[...]
my $cgi = new CGI;

[...]

$fileagetolerance = 5;
$filename = "message.txt";

$newmessage = .... read via http from other website ...; # this message changes most of the time every few minutes.

$fileage = (-M $filename) * 24 * 60; # have the file age in minutes
print "file age of ".$filename.": ".$fileage.", minimum value needed for special action: ".$fileagetolerance."<br>\n";


if ( open( FILE, "<", $filename ) ) {
  $lastmessage = <FILE>; 
  close (FILE);   
} else {
  print "Couldn't read last message. Exiting<br>\n";
  die;
}

if ($newmessage eq $lastmessage) {
  print "Last message is identical with new message. Exiting...<br>\n";
  die;
}

if ($fileage < $fileagetolerance) {
  print "Last message was not long enough ago. Exiting...<br>\n";
  die;
}

sendItOut($newmessage);

if ( open( FILEOUT, ">", $filename ) ) {
  print FILEOUT $newmessage;
  close (FILEOUT);   
  print "Done.<br>\n";
} else {
  print "Couldn't write last message.<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: You've got some logging in there - what does your log say happens?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you'd write a CGI program that is called from cron. What makes it a CGI program? As for your real problem, have you tried turning on `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: You introduce comments in Perl with # not with // ...

Comment: sorry, I just copied the original code and reduced it. of course I didn't use // in the original code

Comment: logging says: everythings fine...
especially it says this:
"file age of message.txt: 47.5, minimum value needed for special action: 5"
though the file was written in a previous run and is no older than 1 minute.

Comment: > I'm struggling to understand why you'd write a CGI program that is called from cron.

I'm calling the cgi page also manually from the outside by supplying some parameters to it. (I do NOT have direct server access...) Anyway, it needs to be a CGI, that's not my problem ;-)

Comment: > I'm struggling to understand why you'd write a CGI program that is called from cron.

I'm calling the cgi also manually from the outside world via http request and supply some parameters to it. (I do NOT have direct server access via console, just call the cgi which is protected via .htaccess) 
Anyway, it needs to be a CGI, that's not my problem ;-)
If I would set "use strict", I'd need to refactor my code a bit...

Comment: "If I would set `use strict`, I'd need to refactor my code a bit." I'll bet that in the course of those refactorings, you would fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I see typo here:
`$fileage = (-M $tfilename) * 24 * 60; // have the file age in minutes`. No such var as `$tfilename`...

Comment: The typo is not there in the real code, I renamed some variables for clarity. But thanks for the hint, I corrected it above!

Comment: Could you replicate this behaviour with simpler version of your code?